# apache redirect to localhost when using passport

Tags: node.js, apache, virtualhost

I host a node application to a server. In my application I used passport for facebook google+ and twitter sign in. but the redirected url goes to localhost:3000.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin exaple@gmail.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
```

when I changed the ProxyPass from localhost to IP address which redirect to that IP. I given domine address, its not working.

Please help me. I just want to redirect to my domine(example.com).

I created app in facebook twitter and google plus having registered with my domine.

My URL

```
 app.get('/:cc/userSignInGoogle', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' }));
app.get('/userSignInGoogle/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }), function(req, res) {
res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make a redirect after a successful auth using passport? Then you should change successRedirect in your code, not in your apache config.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',
 { successRedirect: '/',
   failureRedirect: '/login' 
 }));
```

Comment: @HarisAju and what is inside your "req.session.returnTo"? Are you sure, that it's not a "localhost:3000"? Can you log it into console?

Comment: It doesn't reach redirect action for log. before that google redirect to localhost like this "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2FuserSignInGoogle%2Fcallback.........."